Increase useable size of logical drive in ADAPTEC 6405E RAID 1 array using ARCCONF, after increasing physical disk size
I have just upgraded pair of SATA SSD from 500GB to 1TB in adaptec/microsemi 6405E RAID1 array installed in a Windows Server 2012 machine, by hot swapping disk1, waiting 30 minutes for it to rebuild, hot swapping disk2 and waiting another 30 minutes for that to rebuild. However ARCCONF tells me the logical device is still only 476150MB and windows reports the drive capacity has not increased.
I believe i need to use ARCCONF to increase the size of the logical device, however the documentation is a bit vague and there is no specific example for swapping the disks in a RAID1 array with larger disks. Additionally various documentation seems to use the words device and drive interchangeably.
Can someone confirm i have the correct syntax to increase the logical device size to the maximum available of the physical devices ?
NOTE: ARCCONF reports that LOGICALDEVICE id = 0, and i am assuming as i only have a single RAID adapter in the system, ADAPTER id = 1. Physical devices are reported as Disk1Channel Disk1Id Disk2Channel Disk2Id = 0 0 0 1.
arcconf MODIFY 1 LOGICALDRIVE 0 EXPAND MAX

or is it :
arcconf MODIFY 1 FROM 0 TO MAX

or is it :
arcconf MODIFY 1 FROM 0 TO MAX 1 0 0 0 1


Ok so the answer is :
arcconf modify 1 from 0 to 851936 1 0 0 0 1

where i wanted the revised logical device to be 851936MB which left me about 10% unallocated space which will hopefully prevent slow write speed when the logical device ( drive exposed to windows ) gets full.
The syntax is therfor :
arcconf modify <adapterid> from <logicaldevice> to <size> <raidlevel> <physicaldev1channel> <physicaldev1id> <physicaldev2channel> <physicaldev2id>

However it took several hours which was unexpected, and once ARCCONF had finished applying the change, in order to see the changes in windows disk management, i had to rescan devices. there was no outage to service while it took place.
